# Проблема со скриптом неактивного объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть у меня prefab часто используемый, и скрипт специально написанный для него. Проблема в том что скрипт прикреплённый к нему должен работать в начале сцены а объект в начале сцены неактивный. На данный момент я решил проблему прикрепив скрипт к другому объекту, но поскольку он часто используемый будет сложно каждый раз прикрепить скрипт потустороннему объекту.

---

Как решить эту проблему или как облегчить эту задачу хотя бы?

---

ПН
Скрипт управляет именно этим объектом. В начале он загружает данные и ставит его в объект. На самом деле я делаю панель цветов. Если в начале он не будет активен то начальный цвет будет прозрачным, а надо чтобы он загрузил цвет с прошлой сцены.

Comment: пусть префаб включает в себя объект-пустышку с Вашим скриптом, а дочерним объектом у него будет тот объект, который в префабе сейчас. а при старте сохраняйте ссылку на него и отцепляйте его программно, или оставьте внутри :)

Comment: "Проблема в том что скрипт прикреплённый к нему должен работать в начале сцены а объект в начале сцены неактивный" - возникает сразу два вопроса. Если скрипт должен работать с самого начала, то что там написано такое? Может он не относится к объекту самому, а является неким управляющим скриптом над всем? Менеджером так сказать.  В таком случае можно сделать именно объект менеджер, который будет следить за всеми необходимыми объектами и делать необходимые манипуляции. ПОтому что если объект изначально неактивный, но скрипт должен что-то делать - значит явно нарушена ответственность в скриптах

Comment: @СергейМишин он управляет именно этим объектом. В начале он загружает данные и ставит его в объект. На самом деле я делаю панель цветов. Если в начале он не будет активен то началный цвет будет прозрачным, а надо чтобы он загрузил цвет с прошлой сцены.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ хороший вариант. Скоро попробую. А вы можете сделать это ответом

Comment: Дополните вопрос информацией про цвета и инициализацию, то, что скрипт не должен выполнять что-то за несколько кадров через `Update` - очень полезная информация.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле эту задачу можно решить сразу несколькими способами.

Во-первых нужно понимать, что активный объект отличается от неактивного тем, что **не принимает сообщения от Unity**, соответственно неактивный GameObject не будет ничего делать ни при каких обстоятельствах.

Пойдем другим путем, **все** компоненты в Unity на активном объекте **всегда** получают `Awake()`. В данной ситуации неактивный объект ничем не отличается от активного объекта со всеми неактивными компонентами (по сути, в любой ситуации эти объекты практически ничем друг от друга не отличаются).

Итого имеем **активный** префаб, у которого все компоненты выключены, добавляем к нему следующий компонент:

```
public class InactiveInitialization : MonoBehaviour {
    MonoBehaviour[] components;

    void Awake() {
        // код инициализации, загрузки файлов, etc.

        components = gameObject.GetComponents<MonoBehaviour>();

        // отключаем на всякий данный компонент
        // хотя, по сути, это ни на что не повлияет, Update() и прочие колбеки все равно не определены
        enabled = false;

        Debug.Log("Object is initialized, inactive loader script will be destroyed after EnableComponents() call");
    }

    public void EnableComponents() {
        foreach(var component in components) {
            component.enabled = true;
        }
        Destroy(this);
    }
}
```

`Awake()` сработает по причине, описанной выше, а значит через него можно инициализировать любой компонент этого объекта. Также мы собираем ссылки на все компоненты, чтобы во время рантайма не тратить на это драгоценное время. "Включать" объект нужно строго методом `EnableComponents()`:

`gameObject.GetComponent<InactiveInitialization>().EnableComponents();`

Данный метод довольно быстро включит все прикрепленные к объекту компоненты (т.е. сделаем объект активным) и уничтожит себя, т.к. он был нужен только для инициализации.

Comment: Я использовал ваш ответ совместимо с ответом Stranger in the Q

Answer (score 2):

Нужно сделать так, пусть префаб включает в себя объект-пустышку с Вашим скриптом, а дочерним объектом у него будет тот объект, который в префабе сейчас.

При старте сохраняйте ссылку на него и отцепляйте его программно, или оставьте внутри, это уже на Ваше усмотрение :)

Comment: Я использовал ваш ответ совместимо с ответом RiotBr3aker.

Comment: Как разделить 1 галочка на двоих?)

Comment: @Alt_F4 Уступаю её RiotBr3aker.y